# How to disable the on-screen volume level indicator when changing volume in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, volume

What I want is either change the "on-screen volume level indicator" or disable it completely. By "on-screen volume level indicator" I mean this:

[image: on-screen volume level indicator]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. What version of Linux Mint are you using? What's your desktop environment (Cinnamon, MATE, XFCE)?

Comment: I don't use Mint, but [this link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=243622) *seems* to answer this question.

Comment: My version is Linux Mint 19.3 and I'm using Cinnamon.
As for the link, that explains how to disable the sound, which I already did, what I want is to disable the level indicator that appears on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using MATE desktop,
on a terminal, type :

```
gsettings set org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.media-keys enable-osd false
```